# Do you think you are smart enough for this?

Tags: riddle

> You need me to bake
>
> But I'm not in any home
>
> I drown noise when full
>
> But empty, your voice will roam

Comment: oho... any hints? don't say Preheat the oven

Comment: Good riddle! Stumps me!

Comment: I like this riddle - so many opportunities to propose clearly false yet still entertaining answers

Comment: Was there a correct answer?

Answer (score 10):

I think it is a

> flour silo

because

> you need flour to bake, most people don't have flour silos (and if they did it probably wouldn't fit in your house), cant make a noise in one, but would be big and echo-ey if empty.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please note that answers are usually hidden with ">!" tags ([spoiler notation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers)). Why not take the [tour](/tour) for an easy badge?

Answer (score 10):

Probably not, but maybe:

> Time

You need me to bake

> Takes time to bake

But I'm not in any home

> Time isn't an object

I drown noise when full

> When your time is filled (you are busy) you don't notice other noise

But empty, your voice will roam

> When your time is empty (bored), you are more aware of surrounding noise

Answer (score 5):

My guess:

> A Beaker

You need me to bake:

> The word sounds like "baker" with an 'e'

But I'm not in any home:

> Most people don't have beakers in their home

I drown noise when full:

> Beaker full of liquid suppresses sound.  Also Beaker's Song is sure to drown out any noise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDuebLakCqc

But empty, your voice will roam:

> Shout into a glass beaker and your voice will be amplified

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest a somewhat less serious answer to this riddle:

> Marijuana

You need me to bake

> Getting high is frequently referred to as 'getting baked'

But I'm not in any home

> In areas where weed is illegal, everyone will deny having it in their possession: "It's not in my home."

I drown noise when full

> Thanks to a suggestion by gabbo1092, this one could refer to the 'drowning' bubbling noise a bong makes when in use.

But empty, your voice will roam

> Once the bag is empty/used up, the intoxicated person will experience normal events in a more psychedelic manner. For instance, when speaking, it might sound like someone's voice is echoing in a large chamber.

Comment: Heck, it fits about as well as (or better than) the answers given so far.

Answer (score 1):

It makes me think of an

> exhaust pipe.

You need me to bake

> You need some kind of exhaust or ventilation duct ([e.g.](https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3925/14597290010_387ee2a507_b.jpg)) to let steam and smoke out while baking. @[kanoo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52705/kanoo)'s answer suggests that there is an inebriant sense of "bake" that may call for a pipe too.

But I'm not in any home

> It would defeat the purpose if you ventilated the hot air/steam/smoke back into the house, so the pipe responsible for this must be exterior.

I drown noise when full

> The exhaust pipe on a car, with muffler attached ([e.g.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Scooter_exhaust.jpg)), muffles the sound moving through it.

But empty, your voice will roam

> An unmuffled exhaust pipe can cause a lot of noise as you roam through the neighborhood and it roams in a large radius all around you.

Title: Do you think you are smart enough for this?

> No, I feel like I'm really missing something crucial, including but not limited to the interpretation of the title.